# Create a virtual desktop and share it over the internet

Tags: unity, 12.10, gnome, streaming

I was wondering if there is anyone who has an idea how to do a display trick.

Here is the deal, I have Ubuntu on my laptop and we have a bunch of desktop computers in the university. I can't unplug the cables from the monitor and plug them in my laptop and I am looking for a way to do it wirelessly.

My idea is to create a 'virtual' desktop next to my laptop desktop and then stream this desktop over the internet, maybe skype, maybe some other tool you might suggest, to the university desktop machine, so that I can have two displays.

Thanks in advance!